# Error inflating class fragment in MapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps

I have xml file with my MapFragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

And Fragment using it :

```
public class CallistoMapFragment extends MapFragment {
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, null);
    mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
    setUpMap();
    return v;
}

private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title(
            "Marker"));
}
```

}
When trying to compile get error

> 11-20 15:31:15.343: E/AndroidRuntime(10705): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment

API key in android manifest is right. What wrong?

Comment: Can you Please post your full stacktrace?

Comment: you can not use pass fragment inside fragment xml. you need to add fragment run time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

XML:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
         />
```

Class

```
GoogleMap mMap;
SupportMapFragment mapFrag;

Now set it:

if (mMap == null) {
            mapFrag= (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mMap =  mapFrag.getMap();

            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                // The Map is verified. It is now safe to manipulate the map.

            }
        }
```

Also add this meta Tag within in manifest file.

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="myApiKey"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

While in my case the issue came due to my metadata tag automatically placed outside of application tag like this below.

```
<application android:label="My.Mobile"></application>
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="myApiKey"/>
```

after placing meta-data tag inside application tag issue was gone:

```
<application android:label="My.Mobile">
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="myApiKey"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:Add this in your manifest in application tag

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your project reference Google play services to your project...

Answer (score 0):

if dependencies showing warning or error then you have to change it for latest like as...

change

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'
```

to

```
 compile  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
```

Its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

After almost 1 day trying, I found a problem in my build.xml. The problem was with versions of my libraries...

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'           <-
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'     
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'              <-
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.2'        <-
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.2'              <-
implementation testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
implementation androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
implementation androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```